# Is it possible for an abstract class to force it's children to have a constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, abstract-class

I would like to do something like this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'This is the parent constructor';
    }

    abstract function __construct();
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    // constructor is required as this class extends Foo
    public function __construct() 
    {
        //call parent::__construct() if necessary
        echo 'This is the child constructor';
    }
}
```

But I get a fatal error when doing this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Foo::__construct() in Foo.php on line 8
```

Is there another way to ensure child classes have a constructor?

Comment: Abstract classes won't force that but Interfaces will.

Comment: Why would you want such think anyway? I understand the need about a given method, but what about the constructor?

Comment: @Sebas you can do literally billions of things with a script, you don't think just one of them might necessitate requiring a constructor?

Comment: yes of course, but from my past, to force a class extending another to implement *a* constructor is a bit weird! I'm sure you have your reasons though, no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short no. Non of the magic methods can be declared via the abstract keyword.

If you want to use the old way of constructors, create a method with the same name as the class, and declare it abstract. This will be called upon instantiation of the class.

Example:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'This is the parent constructor';
    }

    abstract function Bar();
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    // constructor is required as this class extends Foo
    public function Bar() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'This is the child constructor';
    }
}
```

I would suggest the use of interfaces for your functionality though.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this way would work but there are many classes that inherit from `Foo` in my actual application. Thanks for the info, will use an interface.